# Recommended Tutorial Videos or Books on Feature Engineering Using Python

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, feature-engineering, feature-extraction, feature-scaling

I will appreciate it if you guys can recommend for me a good hands-on tutorial videos or books on feature engineering using Python. I do not want videos or books that teach only the theory behind feature engineering but one that will show me some codes and how to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are several articles and tutorials online. For example,
[PythonDataScienceHandbook](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/05.04-feature-engineering.html) or [towardsdatascience](https://towardsdatascience.com/feature-engineering-in-python-part-i-the-most-powerful-way-of-dealing-with-data-8e2447e7c69e).
Depend on your particular problem, you can also apply the [Automated tools](https://towardsdatascience.com/automated-feature-engineering-in-python-99baf11cc219) for feature engineering.

Most of these materials have python code and links for your learning.

Answer (score 0):

Feature Engineering for Machine Learning: Principles and Techniques for Data Scientists, this book is the best book for feature Engineering. Once you even partially finish this you'll know what to look out for next!